# The print broke into tangled filaments

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, adhesion

I've just got an Ender-3 Pro printer and set it up according to general recommendations, including bed leveling (I used the "paper in the corners" technique). The test model that comes with the printer (a lucky cat figure) came out perfectly.

After that, I tried to print this model - [Cat Stretch](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1565405). I saw in the comments that others printed it successfully without support on the same printer, so I didn't add it.

Initially, everything was fine and the legs were printed ok, but the print broke into tangled filaments at some point.

[image: 3D printed figure of the cat broke into tangled filaments]

Could somebody please advise what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Was the print detached from the bed? Was it loose when you found it?

Comment: It was still attached when I noticed that it fell apart.

Comment: All legs were attached? Or the back legs came off? I don't see them in this picture. Can you share this G-code file?

Comment: Well, it was a pretty big mess, so hard to remember, but probably yes, the hind legs could be deattached. And I just noticed that for some reason the bed leveling became completely wrong and two prints 8(). I didn't touch the knobs for sure, but the nozzle started to touch the bed and scratched it in some places. I re-adjusted it and am printing the test cube now.

Comment: Such a small model has a very low contact surface with the bed. You can try to print it with brim. These back legs can be problematic to print without such a low contact with the bed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try to print it this way. Here is the model: https://www.sendspace.com/file/v5cujx 

I'm still wondering why the bed became so misaligned after the printing of that cat. As long as I didn't touch the leveling knobs, could it be the Z-motor positioning that went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As it was suggested by @kosteklvp the problem was most likely caused by the detachment of the hind legs from the base. I added a brim and it helped.

[image: Cat]